# wait until condition is true javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I was developing jqueryui plugin.
I have a script which checks if certain libraries are not added then add it. I am using setTimeOut to add libraries in a sequence. Here is my code:

```
  if(typeof jQuery === 'undefined'){ //check if jQuery Exists 

    console.log("jQuery not loaded");
    var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
    script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    script_tag.setAttribute("src",
        "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js");

    (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);

    console.log("jQuery  loaded");

}

setTimeout(function(){
 if (typeof jQuery.ui === "undefined"){

    console.log("jQueryUI not loaded");
    var script_tag2 = document.createElement('script');
    script_tag2.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    script_tag2.setAttribute("src",
        "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js");

    (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] ).appendChild(script_tag2);


}
}, 500);
```

But the problem is that because there are many libraries at it takes too much time. And if I reduce time then I get error that previous library is not added. Instead of passing a number to settimeout function. I want to pass a function which will check if previous library is loaded then add this library. 
I hope that will make you understand about my query.

Thanks

Comment: Listen `onLoad` event of script element...

Comment: Looks like you are reinventing http://requirejs.org/.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(typeof jQuery === 'undefined'){ //check if jQuery Exists 

    console.log("jQuery not loaded");
    var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
    script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    script_tag.setAttribute("src",
        "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js");
    script_tag.setAttribute("onload", "loadJQueryUI()");
    (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);


}
function loadJQueryUI() {
    if (typeof jQuery.ui === "undefined"){
        console.log("jQueryUI not loaded");
        var script_tag2 = document.createElement('script');
        script_tag2.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
        script_tag2.setAttribute("src",
            "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js");
        (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] ).appendChild(script_tag2);   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to search online for a small js loader, otherwise the code below is the sort of layout you need to load as many scripts in sequence. It is not complete nor is it tested. But it shows the principles.

```
//
//
// This is a very basic loader, you can specify the scripts to load as 
// below, I would not bother doing this
// since you can get some very neat js loaders pre built.
// But this demonstrates how an async loader can work.
//
//
var depends = [{"name": "jQuery", "src": "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"},{{"name": "jQuery.Ui", "src": "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"}}];

var asyncLoop = function(o){
    var i=-1;

    var loop = function(){
        i++;
        if(i==o.length){o.callback(); return;}
        o.functionToLoop(loop, i);
    } 
    loop();//init
}

asyncLoop({
    length : depends.length,
    functionToLoop : function(loop, i){

            // DON'T USE EVAL
            // I would prefer to write a helper to check if the 
            // library is in scope, this would require a function to circle dot notation
            // and check the object is in scope ie jQuery.UI or something.something.here.
            //
            if (eval([depends[i].name]) return loop();
            var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
            script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
            script_tag.setAttribute("src", depends[i].src
            (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
            //
            // Load next script on load, this needs a timeout so we can fail gracefully
            //
            script_tag.onload = function(){
                loop();
            }

    },
    callback : function(){
       console.log("loaded");
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try using recursion with `setTimeout();`

```
waitUntilConditionIsMet() {
    if (this.jQueryLibraryExists) {
        setTimeout(this.waitUntilConditionIsMet(), 500);
    } else {
        // add logic for adding jQuery Library
    }
}
```